# Plus/Minus a quantity field

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement addition / subtraction feature on my 4 different product modals. It has the same class names as follows.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-subtract" type="button">-</button>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control no-padding text-center item-quantity" value="1">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-default btn-add" type="button">+</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here's my JS.

```
var minus = document.querySelector("btn-subtract")
var add = document.querySelector("btn-add");
var quantityNumber = document.querySelector("item-quantity");
var currentValue = 1;

minus.addEventListener("click", function(){
    currentValue -= 1;
    quantityNumber.textContent = currentValue;
    console.log(currentValue)
});

add.addEventListener("click", function() {
    currentValue += 1;
    quantityNumber.textContent = currentValue;
    console.log(currentValue);
});
```

However, it's not showing anything in the input field. Any advice?

Comment: None of your query selectors are correct. If you want to select by class the class name needs a . (dot) in front of it

Comment: Hi Martin, replace `quantityNumber.textContent` with `quantityNumber.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some other issues (besides incorrect element-query) here:

- to select a CSS-class use a *dot before class name*: e.g. `.btn-minus`
- to get or set the value of an input control use its *value* property: `quantityNumber.value += 1` (even decrement/increment: e.g. `quantityNumber.value++`)
- if you first set the variable *currentValue* to (constant!) 1 and use in de-/increment then **state is UI-independent**. The user might initially enter 5 in the input-field then hitting the plus-button when your listener changes to 1+1=2.
- CSS-classes for referencing form-controls may work on all controls (independent of the current context). If you have **product-specific quantity** then the use-case might be to enter different quantities for different products/order-lines. So **working with an element ID may be an alternative**.
- there is already a HTML **[number input](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_number.asp)**, which supports these operations `stepUp`/`stepDown` as well as `min`/`max` (see B in example below)
- there may be a **minimum-quantity** (e.g. `0`) allowed: use HTML input-field's `min` property and/or conditionally [disable](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_disabled.asp) minus-button

```js
// product A
var minus_A = document.querySelector("#product_A_form .btn-subtract")
var add_A = document.querySelector("#product_A_form .btn-add");
var quantity_A = document.querySelector("#product_A_form .item-quantity");

minus_A.addEventListener("click", function(){
    quantity_A.value--;
});

add_A.addEventListener("click", function() {
    quantity_A.value++;
});

// product B
var minus_B = document.querySelector("#product_B_form .btn-subtract")
var add_B = document.querySelector("#product_B_form .btn-add");
var quantity_B = document.querySelector("#product_B_form .item-quantity");

// includes button minus disablement if at minimum or below
const minimum = 0;

minus_B.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (quantity_B.value <= minimum) {
      minus_B.disabled = true;
      return; // return to avoid decrementing
    } else {
      minus_B.disabled = false;
    }
    quantity_B.value--;
});

add_B.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (quantity_B.value > minimum) {
      minus_B.disabled = false;
    }
    quantity_B.value++;
});
```

```html
<!-- product A -->
<div id="product_A_form" class="input-group">
  A
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-subtract" type="button">-</button>
  </span>

  <input id="product_A_qty" type="text" class="form-control no-padding text-center item-quantity" value="1">

  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-add" type="button">+</button>
  </span>
</div>

<!-- product B -->
<div id="product_B_form" class="input-group">
  B
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-subtract" type="button">-</button>
  </span>

  <input type="number" class="form-control no-padding text-center item-quantity" min="0" value="1">

  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-add" type="button">+</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, how do I reset the input quantity so that when the modal is closed, it will return back to the default value 1? :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that your selectors were bad and you can't use textContent property on input field to change its value. Code below should do the trick:

```
var minus = document.querySelector(".btn-subtract")
var add = document.querySelector(".btn-add");
var quantityNumber = document.querySelector(".item-quantity");
var currentValue = 1;

minus.addEventListener("click", function(){
    currentValue -= 1;
    quantityNumber.value = currentValue;
    console.log(currentValue)
});

add.addEventListener("click", function() {
    currentValue += 1;
    quantityNumber.value = currentValue;
    console.log(currentValue);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It did work, I overlooked the . in query selector. However, it's only working on the first modal, the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th modal's buttons won't work. Any thoughts? :\

Comment: "you can use"... You mean can't I think :-)

Comment: Try again, I've changed it now and @ADyson you're right - I meant to say you can't :-D

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect queries. You miss '.'

```
var minus = document.querySelector(".btn-subtract")
var add = document.querySelector(".btn-add");
var quantityNumber = document.querySelector(".item-quantity");
```

Comment: Thank you. It did work, however, I need the other modals with the same classes to work as well, should I add the functions in a loop?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sy0jzL2f/8/ - check this, if I understand you correct